# Basis for direct sum components

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a vector space $U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $B=\{(3,3,1)\}$ - basis for $U$. I need to find a basis $C$ for $U^\perp$.

We know that $\mathbb{R}^3=U \oplus U^\perp$. Thus, if $B$ is basis for $U$ and $C$ is basis for $U^\perp$ then $B \cup C$ is basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (direct sum). Now, let's look at the set $\{(3,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$. It is linearly independent and so it is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Why can't we deduce that it is possible that $C=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$? (Obviously $(1,0,0) \cdot (3,3,1)\neq 0$ and so $(1,0,0) \notin U^\perp$, but why the previous reasoning was incorrect?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that $B\cup C$ will be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that doesn't mean any $C$ satisfying this condition will span $U^\perp$. In fact, $\mathbb{R}^3 = U\oplus span\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$, but remember that $V=U\oplus W_1=U\oplus W_2$ does not imply that $W_1=W_2$.

Comment: Basically $A=B\oplus C$ doesn't imply $B=A\C$ or such.

Comment: You're welcome!